Help Me Identify This Type of Outdoor String Light Bulb
I have been stumped trying to find out what type of bulb this is.
I have some strings of outdoor lights and this one string has this unusual bayonet style attachment instead of a typical S14 replacement bulb.
I really don't want to have to rip the strings down as opposed to just buying a box of replacements. No matter what I search for I can't find anything with this type of connector though.




https://honeywellledlighting.com/product/6-pk-replaceable-bulbs-for-st136a1121xx-string-light-mc/
They are out of stock, but you might be able to cross-reference the part number to find the equivalent from another supplier.

Thank you, that helps so much!!
